# Best 5 cards and the kicker

Tags: texas-hold-em

If the board is showing:

T♥ T⋄ A♣ J♠ 6♥

One player has an A⋄ 7♥

The other player has an A♥ 5♣

do they split the pot, or does the `7` becomes the highest kicker.

Comment: It does seem like a duplicate, but perhaps its not such a bad thing to have a few examples of the concept to explain it clearly. If the site ever gets over-run with this sort of thing then maybe I imagine it would be better to close them at that point.

Comment: 7 becomes the highest kicker. It wouldn't be the lowest card on the board.

Answer (score 1):

This pot is split since the *kickers* never get a chance to be used.

Texas Hold'em is all about making the *5-best combination of cards*, regardless of how many of your hole cards are used.

In this particular example, the players have this hand:

Player 1 hand:  T♥ T⋄ A♣ A⋄ J♠

Player 2 hand:  T♥ T⋄ A♣ A♥ J♠

As you see, their hand is identical; they both have `2-pair`.

Their `kickers` are never used since there is already `a higher rank` in the board, the `J`. And since the `J` is the 5th card, the hand stops there and kickers are never used.

This is a well hidden `advantage` of ace-rags if the board gets paired.